# How do I handle a free trial before BUY (not subscribe) using In App Purchase on ios

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to offer a free trial and the option to BUY (Non-Consumable In-App Purchase) on my ios app. I can see that I can offer a trial and then SUBSCRIBE (Auto-Renewable Subscription), but I personally don't like having to pay over and over for a simple app, but I do want to try it first. Is there a way to achieve the same thing when setting the option to buy? I realize I could track the first usage after download, but this presents a couple of issues:

1. Will Apple now approve apps for a trial period - previously they have been rejected, but that was before IAP and subscribe was available at all!
2. How do I prevent the user deleting the app (and any data I might store to know they have activated a trial) and then downloading again?

Or do I have to succumb to the pernicious "subscribe" model or release a "light" version with an upgrade? The last time I went "light", Apple insisted I make so much functionality available, I may well have not bothered with the full version - but that was a while ago.

Comment: Is access to the app, account based? e.g. will I log in with a user/pw combo? If so, you could add a flag to that user, that states whether or not they've purchased the app, and have it shipped behind a paywall in the app that you close after your trial period of X days? This is all assuming you'll have a DB the app connects to upon launch to validate users...

Comment: The app would not require login or to even be connected.

Answer (score 3):

Apple now allows you to add a free trial for Non-Subscription apps. It's a 0 price plan for fixed days. After this trial expires, you can show the non-subscription plan for purchase. The downside is user need to do a purchase again after trials end. But offering a free trial is a good user experience.

> Non-subscription apps may offer a free time-based trial period before
>   presenting a full unlock option by setting up a Non-Consumable IAP
>   item at Price Tier 0 that follows the naming convention: "14-day
>   Trial." Prior to the start of the trial, your app must clearly
>   identify its duration, the content or services that will no longer be
>   accessible when the trial ends, and any downstream charges the user
>   would need to pay for full functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Dont prevent the user from deleting the app. Just store the data online when user hits the trial button, you can store a flag in the web services which can be zero or one based on the user.

Comment: Hmmm - I was trying to avoid needing to be connected at anytime, but maybe as part of "registering for a trial" that might be ok. But do Apple now allow trial periods? I can't find anything in current app store guidelines that says one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this if you only care about iOS 11 is using the new [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) API. It's pretty limited in functionality (it lets you track 2 bits, or 4 cases,  total) but should persist between install.

Comment: Interesting, but I was planning on supporting at least back to iOS9.